# Label Expression creates an extra line on top (VBScript)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, expression

Here is the VBScript I use in Arcmap Label Expression to generate my labels:

```
Function FindLabel ( [label1] , [label2] , [label3] , [label4] , [label5] , [label6] , [label7] , [label8], [label9], [label10], [label11], [label12], [label13], [label14])
Dim s
Dim value
Dim join
Dim label


label = [label1] &[label2] & [label3] & [label4] & [label5]  & [label6] & [label7] & [label8] & [label9] & [label10] & [label11] & [label12] & [label13] & [label14]

s = SPLIT(label ,"|") 

label = " "
For Each value in s
    label= label  & vbNewLine & value
Next


FindLabel = trim(label)

End Function
```

The results are great except I am left with an extra "new line" on top, from which I have to go back to manually delete (attached pic)

[image]

How could I edit the code so it does not create that extra "newline" on top?

Comment: are you sure that [label1] has a vale?  I think if it's NULL, then you it would print a NULL string then make a new line for Label2....

Comment: The field [Label1] should always have a value. If there is no chemical compound, at least the value would be the Name of the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the label with a white space, then for each `s` you add a new line and the `s` value. After the 1st `s`, the label is therefore `white space + newline + s1`

You could add the new line after the `s` value:

```
label = " "
For Each value in s
    label= label & value & vbNewLine 
Next
```

Note that you way want to initialize with an empty char (`""`) instead of a space (`"  "`)

Comment: Thank you! The vnNewLine after the Value fix my problem!